# The requested url was rejected

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a simulation site using selenium .
I launched on a server to start testing it, 
after a will the targeted url is giving this error message while it is navigated to by chrome

> The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.
>   Your support ID is: 8410459054496748680

I tried to navigate to this site as a user and cleaned my browsing history and cache 
and it keeps giving me this error

Comment: What is the url that caused this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve error "The requested URL is rejected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892197/how-to-resolve-error-the-requested-url-is-rejected)

Comment: it is the same problem but the available solutions did not work for me

Comment: `Give the support id to you network engineer to learn the specific reason.` What did your network engineer say to you?

Answer (score 0):

You are block by a firewall ASM.
The data you are trying to pass are detected as threats and your request is denied. You need to resolve this with you Network engineer by providing him the ID.

> NOTE: Cookies cleanup might also work sometimes!

Comment: is there any other possible reason ??

Comment: Probably Not authorized for this action.