# Error: The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I am using R 3.4.4., Os windows 7.

I want to use rvest to make a session and scrape some data. Here is my code:

```
  sess<- html_session("https://www.tomato.com.hr/telefonski-imenik", encoding = "UTF-8")
  test <- read_html(sess, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

If you look at test it says:

```
[2] <body>The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.<br><br>Your support ID is: 9986573 ...
```

does it mean that the site has some kind of protection or there is some other problem?

Comment: I just tried the request on the same page in python and it got the page fine. It might have been a temporary server side issue.

Comment: could you please send python code so I can try?

Comment: What exactly do you need to extract so I can write it? I just tried the request.get and it worked.

Comment: Not sure why, but giving it a user agent makes it work: `html_session("https://www.tomato.com.hr/telefonski-imenik", encoding = "UTF-8", user_agent(''))`

Comment: I also got 200 status code after session in rvest package, but when I called read_html(session) it returns above text. I have also tried with POST function in httr package. Lets say you want to enter "Horvat" in `lname` input and then submit. You can try the extract first output.

Comment: GGamba, your solution works. First time so see this...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892197/how-to-resolve-error-the-requested-url-is-rejected