# Redirect form payment gateway to my url shows "The requested url was rejected."

Tags: android, laravel, progressive-web-apps

I create PWA application with laravel, after I made payment with MPU payment gateway, it will not redirect back to my application and it shows following error.

> The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your
> administrator. Your support ID is: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
>
> [Go Back]

[image: Url redirect error]

Before this error it is work. But, start from a couple of days ago, I'm getting this error and it only happened in `chrome` browser of my android phone. This payment process is doing well in other browsers on my android phone. I already try to clear cache and cookie and also reinstall chrome in my phone but no luck. Other people can use no problem with chrome browser on their phone.

I already read [How to resolve "The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator." error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892197/how-to-resolve-the-requested-url-was-rejected-please-consult-with-your-adminis) and try to do like this. But still getting same error on chrome(android).

I contacted to payment gateway developers and they said no logs for this. And also no error log in my server.

Is there any other possible solutions or clue for this ?

Comment: I looked through a few sites I know, but didn't find a hint of an answer for you. I have question that may seem obvious. It has to be asked to eliminate something. Have you looked to see if MPU changed something on their end?

Comment: @StormyKnight They only said they didn't change anything.